# OpenCV / C++ - Edit all isolated pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

I have an grayscale image, which just contains black and white. There are some isolated black pixels due to noise, which I would like to get rid of. I know that opening and closing might be a solution, but I feel like they are not optimal for my image. So I wrote this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < pixels.rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < pixels.cols; ++j) {
        if ((pixels.at<char>(i, j) == 0) && 
            (pixels.at<char>(i - 1, j) == 255) && 
            (pixels.at<char>(i, j - 1) == 255) && 
            (pixels.at<char>(i + 1, j) == 255) && 
            (pixels.at<char>(i, j + 1) == 255)) {
            pixels.at<char>(i, j) = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to run through my image and check if the pixel is black and his neighborhood is white. If that's the case the pixel should be turned into an white pixel also.
I ran this on an test image, which was created by this Mat:

```
Mat pixels = (Mat_<float>(5, 5) <<
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 0, 255, 0, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 0, 255, 0, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
```

When I ran the code nothing happened, just the original image appeared...

When I ran a simpler version of the code, it worked, so the syntax actually should be correct:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < pixels.rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < pixels.cols; ++j) {
        if ((pixels.at<char>(i, j) == 0)) {
            pixels.at<char>(i, j) = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone find my mistake in this?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see which conditional statement is failing, and what the values are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure is basically correct, but you're creating a `Mat` of `float` and you are accessing it as `char`. You need the type to be the same.

Also your iteration ranges need to be fixed. You may also want to check 8-connection, otherwise your image with the central pixel set to 0 won't work as expected

Remember also that `char` range is [-128, +127], so it will never compare equal to 255.

Here's a working example. I used `uchar` since it's the type you probably need since you're working on a grayscale image:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat pixels = (Mat_<uchar>(5, 5) <<
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 0, 255, 0, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 0, 255, 0, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    for (int i = 1; i < pixels.rows - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < pixels.cols - 1; ++j)
        {
            if ((pixels.at<uchar>(i, j) == 0) &&
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1) == 255) &&      // Top Left
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 0) == 255) &&      // Top 
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 1) == 255) &&      // Top Right
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i + 0, j - 1) == 255) &&      // Left
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i + 0, j + 1) == 255) &&      // Right
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 1) == 255) &&      // Bottom Left
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 0) == 255) &&      // Bottom
                (pixels.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 1) == 255)         // Bottom Right
                )
            {
                pixels.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << pixels;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To provide a little more information about char and uchar, here's a code snippet.  It shows that assigning 255 to a signed char sets its value to -1 (all bits set high), and assigning 255 to an unsigned char sets its value to 255.          http://cpp.sh/5wjwp

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't use the `Mat` directly. I generated an Image with that `Mat` and I load that image via `imread`. Do I have to generate the Image with a Mat as `uchar` also then? I thought it wouldn't make much difference...

Comment: If you load the image using `imread(..., IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` the image will ot of type `CV_8UC1`, i.e. `uchar`. And yes, you need to generate the Mat with correct type. Mat with float type should have values  in range [0,1] to be correctly handled by imread and imwrite.